# How to style Placeholder Text in React Native (Tcomb Form Native)

Tags: react-native, tcomb-form-native

I am using Tcomb Form Native for forms and putting auto tag for placeholder in the options. However I would like to change the style for the text displayed. Is it possible to change that ?

```
var options = {
    auto: 'placeholders',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`<TextInput/>` takes a prop of `placeholderTextColor` additionally the placeholder text should inherit whatever styles you put on the TextInput see the following example here: https://rnplay.org/apps/Yyfuag